# Configure destination ViewController without Segues

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Clean-Swift architecture ([Clean-Swift page](http://clean-swift.com/routing-in-clean-swift/)). I've saw that I can reuse most of the ViewController UI that I have. For example, I have one ViewController for load a single image. Till there are a lot of ViewController's it's a chaos create segues from everywhere to them.

I know that you can instantiate the destination ViewController and then pushing it, but it brokes the Clean-Swift philosophy, due to the scenes can only send data through the router. But the function passDataToNextScene, requires a Segue as parameter.

So I would like to know if there is a way that giving two scenes with her respectives routers, with any segue created through StoryBoard send data to the destination viewcontroller.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using a segue, let the router get the data from the current interactor (define a datasource interface) and let the router configure the destination view controller (`destinationViewController.requiredData = requiredData`).

Comment: It seems obvious now, and you are totally right! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a segue, let the router get the data from the current interactor (define a `RouterDatasource` protocol the `Interactor` conforms to) and let the router configure the destination view controller:

```
// Router code
...
let requiredData = datasource.getRequiredData()
destinationViewController.requiredData = requiredData
...
```